# How to update libcamera camera database

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, libcamera

When I use libcamera-still et al. to access my waveshare OV9281-160 Mono camera I get warning messages like the following:

> [3:37:16.227335845] [26500]  WARN CameraSensorProperties camera_sensor_properties.cpp:141 No static properties available for 'ov9281'
>
> [3:37:16.227431315] [26500]  WARN CameraSensorProperties camera_sensor_properties.cpp:143 Please consider updating the camera sensor properties database

I'm guessing that updating that database will improve performance (speed, image quality) of the camera and so I'd love to update it.

Alas, I have now idea how.  Googling the error message gets me a lot of unrelated errors and other things---everyone seems to just ignore this message.

Comment: About 3 weeks ago, the libcamera is already newer version. I used RPI 4. If not sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade -y